# issues with .className in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var appel = document.getElementById("appel");
    var Banaan = document.getElementById("Banaan");
    var Peer = document.getElementById("Peer");

    function laatZien(divID) {
      var item = document.getElementById(divID);
      if (item.className == "verstopt") {
        item.className = "zichtbaar";
      } else {
        item.className = "verstopt";
      }
      if (divID == "appel") {
        alert("hoi");
        Peer.className = "verstopt";
        Banaan.className = "verstopt";
      }
    }
</script>
```

On my page i have 3 pictures with 3 buttons, and when one of the buttons is pressed, one picture must appear, but the others must go away.

The id's of these pictures are: "appel", "Peer", "Banaan".

When the pictures get the class "zichtbaar" -> `display: block;` and when they get the class "verstopt" -> `display:none;`

The first `if/else` statement works fine: it hides when it is shown, and it shows when it is hidden.

but even though the second if-statement does get triggered(i have tested this), the other pictures dont get hidden.(pictures Peer and Banaan)

And yes i know that i still have to do the last if statement 3x for each picture ;)

Comment: You need to move the script down, below the elements, right above the `</body>` tag.

Comment: can you also explain why this is? thanks btw

Comment: It's because you're using `getElementById` outside the function, and for that to work, the elements have to exist in the DOM, so they have to come before the script tag

Comment: at the time of script execution the elements are not present in the DOM yet, the browser is just loading them. another, imo even nicer solution would be to have a document ready event listener in the head. you write javascript anywhere you want then

Comment: Please post your html as well, so we can see where/when your script gets called

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)

Answer (score 0):

```
function laatZien(divID) {
    var item = document.getElementById(divID);

    appel.className="verstopt";
    Banaan.className="verstopt";
    Peer.className="verstopt";

    item.className="zichtbaar";

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `getElementById` at the moment when the page is still loading. Because appel peer and banaan are not yet available in the DOM the function returns `null`.

You can fix this by putting the script element at the bottom of the body.

You can also wrap the script in a function which gets called when the page is loaded.

Example below:

```
addEventListener('load', function () {
var appel = document.getElementById("appel");
var Banaan = document.getElementById("Banaan");
var Peer = document.getElementById("Peer");

function laatZien(divID) {
    var item = document.getElementById(divID);
    if (item.className == "verstopt") {
        item.className = "zichtbaar";
    } else {
        item.className = "verstopt";
    }
    if (divID == "appel") {
        alert("hoi");
        Peer.className = "verstopt";
        Banaan.className = "verstopt";
    }
}
}, false);
```